# Requesting inner objects with jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath

I can't figure out a jsonpath query. Here is my json:

```
{
"records" : [
    { 
        "a" : "aaa",
        "fields": {
            "key": 1,
            "b": "bbb"
        }
    },
    { 
        "c" : "ccc",
        "fields": {
            "key": 2,
            "d": "ddd"
        }
    },
    { 
        "e" : "eee",
        "fields": {
            "key": 3,
            "f": "fff"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to extract a 'fields' with a certain key. I've tried these queries without success:

```
$..fields[?(@.key == 2)]
$..fields[?(@.key eq 2)]
$.records[*].fields[?(@.key == 2)]
$.records[?(@.fields[?(@.key == 2)])].fields
```

FYI, I'm using this tester to test my queries: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps not the most efficient way, but this seems to do the job

```
$.records[?(@.fields.key == 2)].fields
```